3/4" INNER diameter copper tubing couplers
I brought a section of my bursted pipe to a  local Ace and was surprised to find none of their couplers fit.  Even more surprising is I've not been able [so far] to find couplers online. In both cases they are 3/4" OUTER diameter.
The tubing may be 1970's fare. Should I jerry-rig some kind of connection or buy shark bit/pex something like that?

Rigid pipe is described by inner diameter (so 3/4" pipe is about 7/8" outside). Tubing ("soft" copper) is described by outer diameter. Tubing is usually connected by compression fittings, but you can solder it with the proper fittings.
See also How can I connect to copper pipe which is slightly oversized?.

I just measured the couplings from Ace and they follow what you say here.    The pipes I have are 7/8" outside diameter, so the couplings do not fit over them. Let's hope that the 7/8" couplings arriving today will fit [over the pipes].

The '7/8 inch' couplings are exactly  the same as what I already had tried and are too small. I have not been able to identify the  correct couplers.

ah d'oh .. it's 7/8" pipes.  And yes they're sold online. The 7-11'ish (small-box, but close-by/convenient) Ace Hardware doesn't carry 7/8".
